# Android asyncTask cant pass ArrayList<> as param

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I have this asyncTask:

```
public class CreateZipFile extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Integer, File> {

    Context context;

    public CreateZipFile(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected File doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... files) {
        for(String file : files){
        //DO SMTH
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    public void onPostExecute() {

    }
}
```

however in my foreach loop I get error saying required ArrayList found String. Is it possible that asynctask converts my arraylist to String?

Comment: please read the async task documentation  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need `AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>,` unless you want to pass an array of `ArrayList`. The `...` operator, is called varargs, and it can be accessed like an array. E.g. if you call

```
 new CreateZipFile().execute("a", "b");
```

then, in

```
protected File doInBackground(String... files) {
```

`files[0]` contains `a` and `files[1]` contains `b`. If you still want to pass the ArrayList, then you have to change your code like follows:

```
 for (ArrayList<String> l : files) {
       for(String file : l){
           //DO SMTH
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `protected File doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... files) {` by this way:

```
protected File doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... files) {
        ArrayList<String> passedFiles = files[0]; //get passed arraylist

        for(String file : passedFiles){
        //DO SMTH
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
    Items[] items = new Items[SIZE]; 
    items[0]=ITEM1;
    items[1]=ITEM2;
    items[2]=ITEM3;
    .
    .
    .

    new InsertItemsAsync().execute(items);
```

```
private static class InsertItemsAsync extends AsyncTask<Items,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Items... items) {
          // perform your operations here
            return null;
        }
    }
```